# Scrapy: How to Scrape a Single Image URL

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, scrapy

I have figured out how to scrape all images from a specific URL, but I'm really just trying to scrape a picture of the product on the page. Utilizing this URL for example... https://www.3bscientific.com/us/simshirt-auscultation-system-size-xl-1022828-cardionics-718-3420xl,p_148_32010.html

I'm attempting to scrape the URL of the picture of the shirt from the page and no other images. A hackish way I've been able to do this is:

```
    for image in response.xpath('//img/@src').extract():
        # make each one into a full URL and add to item[]
        picList.append(response.urljoin(image))
    print("PICLIST")
    print(picList[12])
```

I noticed the picture URL is always the 12th in the list, but it feels like there should be a better way to do this giving I only need the url for the 12th picture. I am also unable to hardcode anything because this scraper scrapes multiple products at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a more specific xpath (I included the id).

```py
In [1]: url = 'https://www.3bscientific.com/us/simshirt-auscultation-system-size-xl-1022828-cardionics-718-3420xl,p_148
   ...: _32010.html'

In [2]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url)

In [3]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.3bscientific.com/il/simshirt-auscultation-system-size-xl-1022828-cardionics-718-3420xl,p_148_32010.html> (referer: None)

In [4]: response.xpath('//div[@id="ProductImageContainer"]//a/img/@src').get()
Out[4]: '/imagelibrary/1022828/1022828_01_SimShirt-Auscultation-System-size-XL.jpg'

In [5]: response.urljoin(response.xpath('//div[@id="ProductImageContainer"]//a/img/@src').get())
Out[5]: 'https://www.3bscientific.com/imagelibrary/1022828/1022828_01_SimShirt-Auscultation-System-size-XL.jpg'
```

Comment: Would this same methodology work for this url and grab the picture of the person holding the tablet? https://www.3bscientific.com/us/sam4-online-auscultation-platform-8001149-cardionics-718-4601,p_148_32829.html

Comment: This works perfect for my use case actually! One question... how did you come to `'//div[@id="ProductImageContainer"]//a/img/@src'`? My scraper works for multiple websites to pull product / descriptions and I'm guessing this xpath will vary between websites

Comment: @Bob Yes, it will work for the other url also. I checked it in the browser's devtools, basically I looked what makes it different than other images. And yes the xpath is specifically for products from this website and probably won't work for other websites.

Comment: Would there be a way of programmatically determining what the xpath should be? Like pass in the href `href="/thumblibrary/1022828/1022828_01_1200_1200_SimShirt-Auscultation-System-size-XL.jpg"` and somehow create the xPath from that?

Comment: If you already have the `href` value you don't need to xpath selector.

Comment: How would I utilize the href in your above code? I'm still pretty new to this whole webscraping concept, so my apologies if that is a stupid question

Comment: @bob  superuser is saying that if you have the href then the whole point of scraping the href is moot, since that was the goal all along.  In dev tools you can usually right click on an element and find a `copy as xpath` menu option which might work but,  the xpath is usually absolute and very inflexible so use with caution.  I suggest reading the [short intro to xpath in the scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#xpath-a-brief-intro)  and the additional links included at the bottom of the section